# Most Efficient way to back up/sync large directories over SSH

Tags: files, rsync, synchronization

I'm looking to back up some large directories on a Dedicated Server to another Server on a daily basis using minimal bandwidth

RSync looks like its up to the task but I'm unsure of the best command switches

I would like to do multiple selected directories to one "backup" directory on another machine over SSH

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add that you'd better user `--numeric-ids` flag to preserve uids/gids of your files so they would not be re-mapped to local users.

If you're going to keep historical backups (say, YYYY-MM-DD daliy directories), option `--link-dest=DIR` would be of great use.

In case your data can be effectively compressed (source code, plaintext files, logs) it `-z` can be quite handy.

Otherwise, `-aH` would cover most of your needs.

Comment: If you have lots of hardlinks to synchronize, `--delete-before` (or `--no-inc-recursion`) may reduce bandwidth usage. However, that's a tradeoff: you'll get a delay at the start of `rsync` run because that forces `rsync` to compute all changes needed before transmitting any file data. See the documentation for the other side-effects. This allows hardlinks to be processed efficiently but slows down the initialization a lot (the bottleneck will be defined by the local and remote filesystem performance until all the changes have been computed).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this (from backup server ):

```
rsync \
    -a \
    --bwlimit=100 \
    remote-server:"/path1 /path2 /path3" /local/backup_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H:%M)
```

`--bwlimit=100` stands for al most 100KB/sec

You can use *hard links* with `cp -al` between days, that way you can save a lot of disk space and `rsync` only changed files !

That's how [`rsnapshot`](http://www.rsnapshot.org/) project works.

Comment: Would this be suitable for a cron job, can this be automated?

Comment: Remember that `-a` preserves only a subset of the metadata associated with files. For system backup, that's generally not enough.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` is ok, but remember you need to be running `rsyncd` on one of the machines to take advantage of rsync's [change-detection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Algorithm).

As for the hardlinking sputnick mentions, you might also be interested in [`fdupes`](http://code.google.com/p/fdupes/).

Answer (score 0):

Rsync is indeed the right low-level tool to handle this. Rather than worry about rsync options, use a dedicated backup tools, there are plenty. [Rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org/) is a popular choice, see if your requirements (which you aren't very explicit about) meet its capabilities. [Duplicity](http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/) is another backup tool based on the rsync library.