# How to compress and transfer folders from one server to another over network

Tags: scripting, scp

Do we have any option to transfer folder from one server to another, that is faster and compressible and bandwidth limit settable method? The servers run on Linux.

I tried tar + ssh but I couldn't set bandwidth limit to 3 or 4 MBPS likewise.

Any other service does it?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65338/most-efficient-way-to-back-up-sync-large-directories-over-ssh/

Comment: See also [tar + rsync + untar. Any speed benefit over just rsync?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30953/tar-rsync-untar-any-speed-benefit-over-just-rsync)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) with option `--bwlimit=` to limit bandwidth and `-z` to compress file data during the transfer.  Using SSH as a transport for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
bsdtar cf - . | xz | pv -L 3m | ssh host 'cd /there && xz -d | bsdtar xpSf -'
```

(here using bsdtar as other ones generally don't store all the file metadata).

`xz` is probably the best compression you can get (but is very CPU intensive), `pv` for rate limiting (note that it's 3 mega (2<sup>20</sup>) **bytes** per second).

Add the `--numeric-owner` option to the second `bsdtar` if it's for backup and you want to preserve the uids/gids.

That would be more efficient (in terms of bandwidth and resource on both servers) than using `rsync` (with `xz` compression) for a full transfer, but if you need to resume a transfer or sync folders that have files in common, that's where [`rsync` comes handy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102226/22565) (but read the `rsync` man page  carefully to select which options you need to preserve the meta data that you want to preserve).

Answer (score 0):

To fine-tune network throughput there are also tools such as [cstream](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/cstream.html) or [mbuffer](http://www.maier-komor.de/mbuffer.html).

In addition to `-t num` to throttle data throughput to `num` bytes per second, `cstream`, for example, not only has a `-b num` option to set the block size used for read/write, but also a `-B num` option to buffer an input block up to `num` bytes before writing.

As an alternative to `ssh` and `rsync` you could try `nc (netcat)` or `ncat`, especially if the data stream is not going to go over the internet. `ncat` is part of the Nmap Project and has SSL support though.

```
# netcat + tar + cstream example to throttle network throughput
# requires netcat on both servers
# cf. http://superuser.com/questions/291803/best-way-to-copy-millions-of-files-between-2-servers/
# cstream -T 10 -t 4m </dev/urandom >/dev/null   # test

nc -l -p 2342 | tar -C /target/dir -xzf -                       # destination box
tar -cz /source/dir | cstream -T 30 -t 4m | nc Target_Box 2342  # source box
```